# Como enviar un objeto a la API de Next.js a través de un fetch

Tags: javascript, nextjs

En mi carpeta `/pages/api/reservations` tengo un archivo `index.js` que se encarga de hacer una llamada a un endpoint externo.

En un componente estoy accediendo al archivo anteriormente mencionado al presionar un boton, de esta manera:

```
const handleSubmit = async () => {
    const url = `api/reservations/${content?.email}/${content?.resid}?sendData=true&authuser=${formData.authuser}&cardname=${formData.cardname}&cardnum=${formData.cardnum}&cell=${formData.cell}&expdatemm=${formData.expdatemm}&expdateyy=${formData.expdateyy}&keysval=${formData.keysval}&pool=${formData.pool}&resid=${formData.resid}`;

    const sendData = await fetch(url).then(data => console.log("Response from sendData", data));

    return sendData;
  };
```

Como verán, necesito pasar un objeto `formData` a la API, y la única forma que encontré es pasarlas por medio de parámetros de ruta, entonces los recibo en `req.query`.

Me gustaría poder hacer alguna llamada mas sencilla, pasando una url  `/pages/api/reservations` y un objeto `formData`, en lugar de escribir todos los parametros en la url, me queda muy larga y poco legible y extendible.

Como podria hacer esto?

Answer (score 0):

Se lo pasas en el body de la consulta con metodo POST:

```
const handleSubmit = async () => {
  const url = '/pages/api/reservations';

  const jsonData = JSON.stringify(formData);

  const sendData = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: jsonData
  }).then(data => console.log("Response from sendData", data));

  return sendData;
};
```